# Increase land value for residential building-Simcity

Tags: simcity-2013

How do you most effectively increase land value for specifically residential building?

I'd like to make an upgrade from Small houses and trailers to apartments and skyscrapers.

Answer (score 1):

Your description of "upgrade from Small houses and trailers to apartments and skyscrapers" tells me you want to raise *density*, not *land value*.

- *Density* determines whether a building can hold few, several, or many people.
- *Land value* determines whether a building is for poor, average, or rich people.

So you want to raise density? Density will go up automatically once the building naturally accumulates enough happiness, there's enough other happy-enough buildings around to merge into, and the adjacent road is of sufficient quality. Aside from ensuring that the road can handle it, there is nothing you can do to speed up this process.

Comment: Shoot. Now I feel stupid... Thanks Man! I already got this solution by waiting, but this is helpful! Since I asked this, my city has sprung up and is now thriving.